# Hiding a control in code behind without freeing up space

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change css from code-behind

If I have: `<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="MyClass" runat="Server" />`

I can do: `txt.Visible = false;` to hide the textbox.

But this will free up the space that the text box txt had.
Instead I want to do something like:

```
txt.css("display", "none");
```

How can I achieve this in asp.net code behind?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put your textbox inside a div and make the div visible/invisible ?

Comment: @mason - why can't ? we can make the div runat='server' and make div to be visible/invisible depending upon the condition

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. But I am working on a project where they are using tables, and did not use div. It's made in a way that makes it bad to introduce div, since I have to do a lot of modifications many places

Comment: Then you can follow what Andrei answered. That's the solution for your requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you got your methods the correct way round? I thought visibility:hidden _didn't_ free up space and so it should be what you want. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 3):

Controls have a [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which you can use to set specific CSS rules:

```
txt.Style["display"] = "none";
```

However specifying style in the html element directly is not recommended. Instead you might want to have a class, say `hide`, and append it to the control's css classes:

```
txt.CssClass += " hide";
```

Comment: Andrei, why is it not recommended?

Comment: @States, because inline styles tend to grow into totally unmaintainable thing. If this is just about display, that's probably fine, but for anything else it is better to have a reusable css class defined.